# Definir página inicial do Google Chrome programaticamente

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch

Para definir a página inicial do Internet Explorer, podemos fazer da seguinte forma:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /V "Start Page" /D "http://www.google.com/" /F
```

Mas para o Google Chrome as coisas complicam e não sei a forma correta de interagir com as preferências do mesmo com vista a ter um *script batch* que me defina a página inicial.

Como posso definir a página inicial do Google Chrome programaticamente?

Comment: Apenas para que as pessoas possam te ajudar de uma forma melhor, você porque informar o que te motiva a querer fazer isso?

Comment: Votei para reabrir a pergunta, é perfeitamente válida e a aplicação prática do que é pretendido é imensa. Pessoalmente, em gestão de grandes estruturas, faço uso destas soluções para manter todos os postos de trabalho iguais e/ou resolver rapidamente novas configurações.

Comment: @Zuul também acho válida, ele pode trabalhar em um grande escritório, aonde existem vários computadores que precisam seguir um padrão estabelecido pela empresa, cada computador pode ter mais de um usuário, o BAT seria apenas para poupar o trabalho dele. Para mim é uma questão válida.

Comment: Eu tenho um total de 120 maquinas aqui na empresa para configurar a nova pagina de web da empresa que sera padrao em todos os computadores, e esse batch me ajudaria muito se tambem tivesse aplicação nos navegadores firefox e chrome

Answer (score 1):

Olá

Você pode realizar o download dos templates do Google Chrome neste site - http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates (arquivo .zip)

Extraia o arquivo.

Feito isso vá no Diretor de Políticas, e em Configurações do Computador, Modelos Administrativos, importe o modelo do Chrome (ADM, pt-br).

Pronto, vá em Configurações do computador, Modelos Administrativos, Modelos administrativos clássicos (ADM), Google, Google Chrome, Página Inicial, Configurar url da página inicial.

Coloque a página desejada e pronto.